# How to run NSTimer in background beyond 180sec in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, timer, nstimer

I have tried this but not working more than 180 sec in iOS 7 and Xcode 4.6.2. Please help me

```
    UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
        UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
       bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
            [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        }];
        NSTimer  *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:20 target:self   selector:@selector(timerMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
     -(void) timerMethod{

     NSLog(@"in timerMethod");
    }
```

Comment: checkout this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9623490/905514

Comment: @Arvind-Systematix actually i have xcode 4.6.2 version . Will this soln work on that Xcode version?

Comment: @Arvind-Systematix i need this functionality for IOS 7 and xcode 4.6.2 version.

Comment: How you are using IOS 7 with Xcode 4.6 as it was introduced in XCode 5? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode. While with IOS 7, you have feature to on/off refreshing app in background.

Comment: I agree with your point, but my project is developed in Xcode 4.6.2 and it is working fine on iOS 6 device but not on iOS7 device

Answer (score 11):

Unless you enable one of the `Background modes`, it is not gonna work.

#### Why?

- You have around 10 minutes of background execution after this the timer is stopped by ios.
- The timer will not fire after app is locked (iOS7), since  ios suspends the foreground app and `bgTask` will not    get fire again.

There is some workarounds, consider to check below question:

[iphone - NSTimers in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8943214/iphone-nstimers-in-background?rq=1)

[Scheduled NSTimer when app is in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8415870/scheduled-nstimer-when-app-is-in-background?lq=1)

[NSTimer on background IS working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187741/nstimer-on-background-is-working/17445679)