# Background timer IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, timer, background

In my app the user can planify an event, thanks to a timer.
I want this timer to work even if the app is in background.
How can I do that ?!

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerFired) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Comment: This question has been asked before. Look at this response: [click here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22628922/how-to-run-nstimer-in-background-beyond-180sec-in-ios-7

Comment: I think local notifications will do this

Comment: When apps are going into the background all timers are canceled. You should use `UILocalNotification` for this. When your app is in the background it may not run any code, unless it fall into one of the background running modes. Since Apple is trying to increase battery life you should not keep your app running in the background longer then needed. So if you want to inform the use about an upcoming event use `UILocalNotification`

Comment: i have already seen theses post. A notification isn't useful to launch code, does it ?

Comment: Can you do some more clarification of your objective..??

Comment: Well, I want to be able to launch a code after a period of time, potentially higher to 10 minutes, even if the app is in background. It seems difficult to do it !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trigger some actions after a period even if the app is in background Local notifications can help you.

Refer  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html

And there is tutorial here http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-local-notification-tutorial/

Note : NSTimer will stop on app entering background

Comment: Thank you ! but actually the goal of my app is to launch a code when the user isn't using the phone ... So a notification isn't suitable !