# Sending GPS coordinates every x minutes with iOS - Core Location won't stop updating

Tags: ios

I am trying to send GPS data information to our server about every 5 minutes, no matter if the app is running or if it's in the background. I can get it to run but it seems to run constantly. I set up a timer to send every 10 seconds for testing but it just keeps sending. I don't think it's the timer that is wrong, I believe locationManager isn't stopping and I don't know why.

This is my code

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{

NSLog(@"Went to Background");

UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}];

[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self.locationManager selector:@selector(startUpdatingLocation) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
self.locationManager.delegate = self;

[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self.locationManager selector:@selector(startUpdatingLocation) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy <= 100.0f) {
    // Use json and send data to server
    ...
    ...

    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    self.locationManager = nil;
    self.locationManager.delegate = nil;
}
}
```

It does the same thing no matter if it's in the background or foreground. Is there something else I need to do to stop locationManager from updating?

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say it runs erratic that's in reference to the timing? ie not every 10 seconds on the dot?

Comment: Well, I'm not 100% sure what it's doing. I think the timing is running okay. I believe that locationManager is the problem and it won't stop. But yes it is running about every second.

Comment: What happens if you remove the timers? They seem to restart location updates every 10s.

Comment: I removed the timer and it did seem to only run once. I added it back in and it kept running. I did notice that when I added it in, it runs once at the beginning, waits 10 seconds then it keeps running every second. So I guess the problem is something with the timer.

Comment: Why do you need the timer at all? Location manager continues to send updates as long as you don't call stopUpdatingLocation. You never cancel the timer either so it will restart the service over and over...

Comment: Because I need to send the user's location to our server every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To send the location periodically to the server, you want to store and compare a date when updates are received, don't use timers as they are unreliable [when the app is in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901398/nstimers-running-in-background).

```
@implementation
{
    NSDate* _lastSentUpdateAt;
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"Went to Background");
    // Update in 5 minutes.
    _lastSentUpdateAt = [NSDate date];
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
// ...

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    // Accuracy is good & 5 minutes have passed.
    if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy <= 100.0f && [_lastSentUpdateAt timeIntervalSinceNow] < -5 * 60) {
        // Set date to now
        _lastSentUpdateAt = [NSDate date];

        // Use json and send data to server
        ...
        ...
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: I went ahead and tested this and it does work correctly but I'm afraid it will eat a lot of the battery.

Comment: That is the only way to do it. Background location tracking is quite battery intensive.